# Swift 4 Label attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, swift4

I'm moving from swift 3 to swift 4.  I have UILabels that I am giving very specific text properties to the label.  I'm getting an 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value' error when strokeTextAttributes is being initialized.  I'm totally lost to be frank.

In swift 3 the of strokeTextAttributes was [String : Any] but swift 4 threw errors until I changed it to what it is below.

```
let strokeTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue : UIColor.black,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth : -2.0,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    ] as! [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]


chevronRightLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "0", attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

Comment: `NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue` => `NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor` instead?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@Larme's comment about the `.rawValue` not being needed is correct.

Also, you can avoid the force cast that crashes your code using explicit typing:

```swift
let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .strokeColor : UIColor.black,
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
    .strokeWidth : -2.0,
    .font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
]
```

This gets rid of the repetitive `NSAttributedString.Key.`, too.

Comment: and if I want use the dic and specify range at same time, is there a way to do that?

Comment: All the `static let`s from [NSAttributedStringKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey) can be used, so range isn't supported as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 16):

In `Swift 4.0+`, attributed string accepts json (dictionary) with key type `NSAttributedStringKey` or `NSAttributedString.Key`.

So you must change it from `[String : Any]` to

*Swift 4.1 & below -* `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]` &

*Swift 4.2 & above -* `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`

#### Swift 4.2

Initialiser for `AttributedString` in Swift 4.2 is changed to `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?`

```
public init(string str: String, attributes attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? = nil)
```

Here is sample working code.

```
let label = UILabel()
let labelText = "String Text"

let strokeTextAttributes = [
     NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor : UIColor.black,
     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
     NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth : -2.0,
     NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
   ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: labelText, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

#### Swift 4.0

Initialiser for `AttributedString` in Swift 4.0 is changed to `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?`.

```
public init(string str: String, attributes attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]? = nil)
```

Here is sample working code.

```
let label = UILabel()
let labelText = "String Text"

let strokeTextAttributes = [
     NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor : UIColor.black,
     NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
     NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth : -2.0,
     NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
   ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: labelText, attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
```

Look at this Apple Document, for more info: [NSAttributedString - Creating an NSAttributedString Object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 1):

> `NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue` is of type `String`
>
> `NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor` is of type `NSAttributedStringKey`

So its unable to convert `String` to `NSAttributedStringKey` .
You have to use like below:

```
let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor : UIColor.black,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
    NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth : -2.0,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Attributed text with multiple colors**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString 
{
@discardableResult func DustyOrange(_ text: String, Fontsize : CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString 
{
    let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: Fontsize)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 242.0/255.0, green: 97.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) ]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text, attributes: attrs)
    append(boldString)
    return self
}
@discardableResult func WarmGrey(_ text: String, Fontsize : CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: Fontsize)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 152.0/255.0, green: 152.0/255.0, blue: 152.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) ]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text, attributes: attrs)
    append(boldString)
    return self
}
}
```

**Now you can Execute the function something like this to use as a globally**

```
func FormattedString(Orange : String, WarmGrey : String ,fontsize : CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString 
{
   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
   paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1
   paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 1
   let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
   formattedString
    .DustyOrange(Orange, Fontsize: fontsize)
    .WarmGrey(WarmGrey, Fontsize: fontsize )
  formattedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: formattedString.length))
   return formattedString
}
```

**You can use globalized function like this**

```
 yourLabelName.attributedText = FormattedString(Orange: "String with orange color", WarmGrey: " String with warm grey color.", fontsize: 11.5)
```

**Attributed text with image**

```
func AttributedTextwithImgaeSuffix(AttributeImage : UIImage , AttributedText : String , buttonBound : UIButton) -> NSMutableAttributedString 
 {
   let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: AttributedText + "  ")
   let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
   image1Attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: ((buttonBound.titleLabel?.font.capHeight)! - 
  AttributeImage.size.height).rounded() / 2, width: 
  AttributeImage.size.width, height: AttributeImage.size.height)
  image1Attachment.image = AttributeImage
  let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
  fullString.append(image1String)
  fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: ""))
  return fullString 
}
```

you can use "NSTextAttachment" with your button label like this.

```
   yourUIButton.setAttributedTitle(AttributedTextwithImgaeSuffix(AttributeImage: desiredImage, AttributedText: "desired UIButton title", buttonBound: yourUIButton), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.x, this should look like :

```
        let strokeTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -2.0,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    ]
```

Comment: `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` That's an old name, no? That's not a `NSAttributedStringKey`.

Comment: It is an NSAttributedStringKey according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsforegroundcolorattributename

Comment: In Objective-C, not in Swift. If I put that code in Swift, it says "Use of  unresolved identifier" for each one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change particular string value so that below answer is helpful you:-

let subStr = "Hello"
 let allStr = "Hello World"

```
    let newStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: allStr)
    newStr.addAttribute(kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey, value:  UIFont.init(customFont: .MyriadPro_R, withSize: 18)!, range: (allStr as NSString).range(of: subStr))
    newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.PrimaryColor, range: (allStr as NSString).range(of: subStr))
    self.stateLbl.attributedText = newStr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = systolicString + " / " + diastolicString

let newStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
// I have static ranges, but you can also extract them dynamically
let systolicRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 2)
let backslashRange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 1)
let diastolicRange = NSRange(location: 5, length: 2)

newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value:  UIFont.ubuntuRegular(28), range: systolicRange)
newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(hexString: "042f57"), range: systolicRange)

newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value:  UIFont.ubuntuLight(23), range: backslashRange)
newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(hexString: "6485a3"), range: backslashRange)

newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value:  UIFont.ubuntuRegular(18), range: diastolicRange)
newStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(hexString: "042f57"), range: diastolicRange)
// my UILabel
valueLabel.attributedText = newStr
```